# Add Response call back when using retrofit with rxjava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I am using retrofit with Rxjava to get response from API as you can see the method i am using i can't see what's coming in the response and offcourse i don't need to becuase i am providing GsonConverter to retrofit but for some debugging reason i need to see the response that coming from API. How can i do this, what code i need to add.

```
public interface ProductApiService
{
    String END_POINT = "http://beta.site.com/index.php/restmob/";

    @GET(Url.URL_PRODUCT_API)
    Observable<Product> getProducts(@Query("some_id") String cid);

    class Creator
    {
        public static ProductApiService getProductAPIService() {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
                    .create();
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(ProductApiService.END_POINT)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            return retrofit.create(ProductApiService.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only do this as of Retrofit 2: Change the return type to include `Response`:

```
@GET(Url.URL_PRODUCT_API)
Observable<Response<Product>> getProducts(/* ...etc... */);
```

You can also use `Observable<Result<Product>>` if you want to see *all* possible errors in `onNext` (including `IOException`, which normally uses `onError`).

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Lew's approach is quick and contains the least amount of boiler plate code. However, this may force you to refactor your networking logic. Since you mention needing this for debugging purposes, perhaps using a configured `OkHttpClient` with [Interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) is a less intrusive strategy.

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request req = chain.request();
            Response resp = chain.proceed(req);
            // ... do something with response
            return resp;
        }
    })
    .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(httpClient)
    .baseUrl(ProductApiService.END_POINT)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build();
```